# Bluetooth Inputstream Android 2.2

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream

I'm trying to connect a bluetooth device and to read out information from it.
I've used the Bluetooth chat example and changed the UUID tp SPP mode.
The connection works, but the Information that I get from the Inputstream is wrong.
The transmitted String is 20 signs long, but the Inputstream just returns a 7. The rest of the bufferstream is empty.

Does anyone has a clue?

Comment: Impossible to answer without looking at your code.

Answer (score 1):

After write try flushing the transmitter's stream.

And on the receiver you will need to wait till you receive the expected bytes.

SPP does not have packet boundaries. So you can receive the packets in multiple chunks and you need have some logic to determine packet boundaries.

Comment: Well I'm not able to flush the transmitter's stream, the device is bought.

Comment: I've tried to buffer the stream by using the BufferedReader Method, but the receive buffer is empty.